# Export web table to csv in python

Tags: python, html-table, export

I want to export the table in this website

https://www.timeanddate.com/moon/phases/usa/new-york?year=2000

to a csv.

Here is the code I have written in python:

```
import urllib.request


web = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.timeanddate.com/moon/phases/usa/new-   york?year=2000")
s = web.read()

html = etree.HTML(s)



tr_nodes = html.xpath('//table[@id="Report1_dgReportDemographic"]/tr')


header = [i[0].text for i in tr_nodes[0].xpath("th")]


td_content = [[td.text for td in tr.xpath('td')] for tr in tr_nodes[1:]]


df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(td_content))


print(df)


df.to_csv('my data.csv')
```

But i get this errror:

```
    header = [i[0].text for i in tr_nodes[0].xpath("th")]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can somebody tell me what i am doing wrong, please?

Comment: how did you import etree? please post all imports

Comment: What is in `tr_nodes`?